# pytorch Dataloader error "Too many open files" when yielding an int

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to implement a custom IterableDataset in which I read words from a file, get theirs unique id, gather them and return them batched.

```py
import os
import torch
import tqdm
from torch.utils.data import IterableDataset, DataLoader
import vocab  # C++ class bound to python with pybind11

class MyIterableDataset(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, file_path, v, num_workers=4):
        super(MyIterableDataset).__init__()
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.file_size = os.stat(file_path).st_size
        self.v = v  # vocab object, bound from a C++ class with pybind11

        chunk_size = self.file_size // num_workers
        start = 0
        end = chunk_size
        bonus = self.file_size - chunk_size * num_workers
        if (bonus > 0):
            end = chunk_size + 1
            bonus -= 1
        self.endpoints = [(start, end)]
        for i in range(1, num_workers):
            start = end
            if (bonus > 0):
                end += chunk_size + 1
                bonus -= 1
            else:
                end += chunk_size
            self.endpoints.append((start, end))

    def read_word(self, f):
        ch = ''
        word = ""
        while True:
            ch = f.read(1)
            if not ch:
                return ''
            if (str.isspace(ch)):
                if len(word) > 0:
                    break
                if (ch == '\n'):
                    return "\n"
                else:
                    continue
            word += ch
        return word

    def parse_file(self, start, words_to_read, id):
        words_read = 0
        f = open(self.file_path, "r")
        f.seek(start, 0)
        if id > 0:
            while True:
                ch = f.read(1)
                if not ch or str.isspace(ch):
                    break
                start += 1
            f.seek(start, 0)
        while True:                
            word = self.read_word(f)
            if word and word != "\n":
                wid = self.v.word2id(word)
                if wid != -1:
                    words_read += 1
                    yield wid  # if I yield 'word' instead, everything works. You can also yield 1 and you get the error
            if words_read >= words_to_read or not word:
                break
        f.close()
                
    def __iter__(self):
        worker_info = torch.utils.data.get_worker_info()
        words_to_read = self.v.get_train_words() // worker_info.num_workers
        start, end = self.endpoints[worker_info.id]
        return self.parse_file(start, words_to_read, worker_info.id)
```

Upon running a DataLoader over my dataset with

```py
num_workers = 7
v = vocab.Vocab("./text8")  # Vocab is a C++ class bound to python with pybind11
ds = MyIterableDataset(file_path=file_path, v=v, num_workers=num_workers)
wids = [j for _, j in tqdm.tqdm(enumerate(DataLoader(ds, num_workers=num_workers, batch_size=10)))]
```

whenever I yield the **word id** I get the following error:

```py
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-04575fb9c982> in <module>
      2 
      3 t0 = time.time()
----> 4 tokens = [j for _, j in tqdm.tqdm(enumerate(DataLoader(ds, num_workers=num_workers, batch_size=10)))]
      5 print()
      6 print(time.time() - t0)

<ipython-input-18-04575fb9c982> in <listcomp>(.0)
      2 
      3 t0 = time.time()
----> 4 tokens = [j for _, j in tqdm.tqdm(enumerate(DataLoader(ds, num_workers=num_workers, batch_size=10)))]
      5 print()
      6 print(time.time() - t0)

~/miniconda3/envs/word2gm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py in __iter__(self)
   1165 
   1166         try:
-> 1167             for obj in iterable:
   1168                 yield obj
   1169                 # Update and possibly print the progressbar.

~/miniconda3/envs/word2gm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    433         if self._sampler_iter is None:
    434             self._reset()
--> 435         data = self._next_data()
    436         self._num_yielded += 1
    437         if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

~/miniconda3/envs/word2gm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
   1066 
   1067             assert not self._shutdown and self._tasks_outstanding > 0
-> 1068             idx, data = self._get_data()
   1069             self._tasks_outstanding -= 1
   1070             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable:

~/miniconda3/envs/word2gm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _get_data(self)
   1032         else:
   1033             while True:
-> 1034                 success, data = self._try_get_data()
   1035                 if success:
   1036                     return data

~/miniconda3/envs/word2gm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _try_get_data(self, timeout)
    897             except OSError as e:
    898                 if e.errno == errno.EMFILE:
--> 899                     raise RuntimeError(
    900                         "Too many open files. Communication with the"
    901                         " workers is no longer possible. Please increase the"

RuntimeError: Too many open files. Communication with the workers is no longer possible. Please increase the limit using `ulimit -n` in the shell or change the sharing strategy by calling `torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')` at the beginning of your code
```

while if I yield the **word** everything works!
Can someone help me understand why this is happening in the first place?

Comment: every system has some limit how many files it can keep open (it needs to reserver memory for information which files are open) and it seems you reach this limit. Did you try to use in system mentioned `ulimit -n` to change this limit ?

Comment: Yes, I know, but here something strange it is happening: this happen only if one returns an integer, if you return a string nothing happens and all works like charms; so, I did not try to set the limit, also because it's very high

Comment: you would have to check in source code (or maybe in documentation) how `DataLoader` uses values which you yield. Maybe for integers it runs different method which needs to open new file.

Comment: Yeah, I will try to look at dataloader.py file